# Pygame mixer in a subprocess does not work

Tags: python, audio, subprocess, pygame, mixer

Debian OS. I call a subprocess

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "/home/pi/play_sound.py"])
```

And in play_sound.py, I play a sound with:

```
def load_sound(url):
    class NoneSound:
        def play(self): pass
    if not pygame.mixer or not pygame.mixer.get_init():
        return NoneSound()
    fullname = url
    try:
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(fullname)
    except pygame.error, message:
        print 'Cannot load sound:', fullname
        raise SystemExit, message
    return sound
```

The problem is that when I run play_sound.py separately, it works fine. But when I call it as a subprocess of another py file, it does not play the sound.

Comment: any error messages? the file might not be seen, when launching it from another process

Comment: why not `import play_sound` and then just call `load_sound` whenever you need to?

Comment: Maybe the parent process also initializes the mixer, and you cannot have two processes with the mixer at once?

Comment: No error at all. play_sound is a GUI that plays many sounds depending on the keyboard input. So I can't just simply import it in the main.py file.

Comment: Does `from pygame.locals import *` also import mixer? How can we "export" it out of the program?

Comment: Everything does work in Windows but not in Debian :(

Comment: I solved it. We need to initialize `pygame.mixer.init()` then quit it before calling the subprocess `pygame.mixer.quit()`.

Comment: Answering a side question:  from pygame.locals import *   does not import mixer.   from pygame import *   does, but it does not initiate pygame.mixer.